# SSRS open file link in new tab or window

Tags: javascript, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I have a few reports that show a link to invoices (.pdf files) that are held on our network share.

I use this on the text box property to to action to allow the user to click on it and view the invoice:

```
="javascript:void(window.open('file:"+Fields!invoice_link.Value+"','_blank'))"
```

When the report is running, I can hover over the link and the correct link address is displayed in Chrome and Edge :

[image: Hover link]

When I click on the link, both EDGE and CHROME do nothing. When I right click and select open in new tab / window - it get this :

[image]

This works fine as expected in Internet Explorer - but this is no longer an option.

Things I've done so far :

- I have allowed popup in both browsers
- I have added the reportserver site as trusted site in security settings
- I have added extensions that allow Local file links in the browser
- I have allowed javascipt to run

Nothing seems to make any difference in opening the link.

I have confirmed that the file that the invoice_link field resolves to is available and accessible.

Does anyone have any other ideas? I can't seem to find anything other than the javascript option to open files

Comment: it's probably a protocol issue - i.e. modern browsers tend to prevent access to `file:///` URLs for security reasons ... pretty sure there's a command line option for Chrome, and therefore probably Edge, that will turn off this "protection" - it used to be `--allow-file-access-from-file` though, it's probably changed since 2013

Comment: I'm assuming the page is loaded using `file:///` protocol of course

Comment: @KJ - I've removed the blank and it makes no difference unfortunately. Same behavior.

Comment: @Bravo -  chrome with the mentioned --allow-file-access-from-file made no difference. Same behavior. what do you mean by file:/// ? why 3 slashes? It resolves only to file://

Comment: file procotol usually looks like file:/// ... URL's are `protocol://` `host` `/path` ... so file always looks like `file:///` ... doesn't it? since the host is nothing

Comment: @Bravo the file link is (and always has been) file://server/path/filename.pdf  .. (only 2 slashes and not three).. this worked in IE.. just not in Chrome and Edge..

Comment: sorry if I confused you ... I've never seen a "server" in a `file://` URL before, I'm sure it's valid - but then, I NEVER use html over anything other than http[s] - regardless ... `file://` protocol is severely limited in modern browsers - that's why it works in IE and nothing else - did you know that Edge has an IE mode?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. Looks like the only way forward is to remove the Javascript.